# Aggregate group multiple _id and access

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, mongoose, aggregate

I want to display a collection with Angular2 with *ngFor.

I tried something like `*ngFor ="let x in data" {{x._id.category}}` but it didn't work.

[image]

How can I display this object or is there a way to do it with mongoose?

```
gquery= [{
    $group: {
        _id: { category: '$category', specCategory: '$specCategory' },
        total:{ $sum:1 }
    }
}];

Experiences.aggregate(gquery, function (err, results) {    
    callback(err, results || {min: 0, max: 0});
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-sm-3">
    <select class="guest categorydd" [(ngModel)]="category_search" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" (ngModelChange)="changeCategory($event)">
        <option value="Alle Kategorien" >All Categories</option>
        <option *ngFor="let x of countedCategory " value="{{x._id}}"> {{x._id}} ({{x.total}})</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

**Component file**

```
countedCategory: any[];
this.countedCategory = data[0].priceBoundaries;
```

Comment: Can you show us your component and template?

Comment: See above. I added the part where *ngFor is applied

Comment: and your component/controller? i.e we need to see where you define `countedCategory`

Comment: ok done. Within the data[0].priceBoundaries I am passing the data into countedCategory.

Comment: there's still not enough information, you need to reduce the complexity of the problem to it's minimal state and show us all the code in between.

Comment: If you want to debug it I suggest you use the | json pipe like {{x | json}} will display all what is x in text form

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, you should try something like this:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <select class="guest categorydd" [(ngModel)]="category_search" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" (ngModelChange)="changeCategory($event)">
        <option value="Alle Kategorien" >All Categories</option>
        <option
          *ngFor="let x of countedCategory"
          [value]="x._id.category + '.' + x._id.specCategory">
          {{x._id.category}}: {{x._id.specCategory}} ({{x.total}})
        </option>
      </select>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name:string;

  category_search;
  countedCategory = [
    {
      _id: { category: 'reisen', specCategory: 'romantik' },
      total: 100
    },
    {
      _id: { category: 'reisen', specCategory: 'abenteuer' },
      total: 77
    },
    {
      _id: { category: 'reisen', specCategory: 'essen' },
      total: 186
    }
  ];

  constructor() {
    this.name = 'Angular2'
  }

  private changeCategory(event: any) {
    console.log(event);
  }
}
```

You can't use an object as `value` it. It would be result in `[object object]`!

You need an unique-key or create one like in my example above.

live-demo: https://plnkr.co/edit/uy5VS9cOt73qY37kQ00X?p=preview

Comment: I am using mongoose to get multiple ids. With you example I know how I can handle it but it is not what I am searching. I need to access the object {id: {category:data, specCategory:data}}

Comment: I am not sure wheres your problem. please provide a complete JSON-Object/Array as an example. If its easier, provide a "temporary" german description, too.. :)

Comment: Hello unfortunately not. If I group two ids like that _id: { category: '$category', specCategory: '$specCategory' }, I am not able to access to specCategory via *ngFor. If I use just one _id then it working fine but I need the counted values for both _ids.

Comment: Would be great to see that JSON for non working "grouping".

Comment: For example I am getting following json within array  [ { _id: { category: 'Travel', specCategory: 'Hotel' },
    total: 2 } ] It is counting category and I need also the count of the specCategory

Comment: please join this chat: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135929/aggregate-group-multiple-id-and-access